# How to select the data according to user choice in VBA excel 2010 script without lose the original data?

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to make an excel with `VBA` file which gets an input from the user `1`,`2` or `3` :

1. How can I run it while opening the `xslm` file ?
2. Assuming I have this table in my file:

[image]

the `common data` is useful for column `A` `B` and `C` unique content.
I would like to use the code bellow, so depends on the user input, it will select the unique data from `A`,`B` or `C`  to the place of `A's` unique data. **BUT** I want that the **data of column A will be reusable** for future use, e.g. if the user will provide `input_num=1` so the data will be `A's` `unique data`

```
Sub main()
MsgBox ("welcome")

Dim input_num As Integer

input_num = InputBox(Prompt:="please select device", Title:="select device", Default:=3)

If input_num = 1 Then

    ' use the first column

ElseIf input_num = 2 Then

    ' use the second column

Else

    ' use the third column

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
1. How can I run it while opening the xlsm file ?

2. Using the column based on User input
```

To run the code when the Excel file starts you can use

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

End Sub
```

Any code that you will put here will run provided macros are enabled in your file. For example, you will see a message box "Hello World" when you open the file which has the below code.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    MsgBox "Hello World"
End Sub
```

The `Workbook_Open()` goes in the Workbook Code area as shown in the screenshot below

[image]

Now regarding your 2nd question

In Excel, you can refer to columns not only by names but also numbers so for example

Column A can be referred to as

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:A")
```

or

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(1)
```

This makes your job easier as you can now directly refer to the column based on the user input. For example

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    MsgBox "welcome"

    Dim input_num As Variant

    input_num = InputBox(Prompt:="please select device", _
    Title:="select device", Default:=3)

    Select Case input_num
        Case 1, 2, 3
            With Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(Val(input_num))
                '
                '~~> Do what ever you want
                '
            End With
    End Select
End Sub
```